# Change the text of an anchor tag when clicked in ng-click method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an anchor tag which when clicked should change it's text in the ng-click function. Can someone pleas help me out on this?
Below is the code:

```
<div ng-app="Test">
<div ng-controller="Foo">
    <a class="anchClass" ng-click="hi($event)">click me</a>
</div>

 angular.module('Test',[]).controller('Foo', function ($scope, $element) {
    $scope.hi = function (e) {
       var elem = angular.element(e.srcElement);
        elem.val("Search");
    } 
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use $event.currentTarget to change current element's text

```js
 angular.module('Test', []).controller('Foo', function($scope, $element) {
   $scope.hi = function(e) {
     e.currentTarget.text = "Search";
   }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="Test">
  <div ng-controller="Foo">
    <a class="anchClass" ng-click="hi($event)">click me</a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks you, this helped :)